# Template for different category on woocommerce product

Tags: plugins

I've made a custom template for a category called "shop" on the products tab. I've read some of the previous topics that mention doing an if conditional to the templete checking the category its in.

I've tried this and had no luck so went to making a template called single-product-shop.php, I then wrote a conditional to load the particular page template and placed it within single-product.php.

However Now I seem to generate a php warning.

```
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php
        if( has_term( 'shop', 'product_cat' ) ) {
            $file = 'single-product-shop.php';
        } else {
            $file = 'single-product-default.php';
        }

        global $woocommerce;

        load_template( $woocommerce->template_url . $file );
?>

                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

If someone could please point out what I'm doing wrong, I would be most greatful.

Thanks

Comment: where do you put `single-product-shop.php` template ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Woocommerce has it's own function [`woocommerce_get_template_part()`](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-woocommerce_get_template_part.html#561-587) for loading template parts, use it like this:

```
woocommerce_get_template_part( $slug, $name );
```

which refers to the according file `{$slug}-{$name}.php` or used like this:

```
woocommerce_get_template_part( $slug );
```

refers to the file `{$slug}.php`, it automatically

> Looks in yourtheme/slug(-name).php and yourtheme/woocommerce/slug(-name).php

it can be used with a conditional like this:

```
    if( has_term( 'shop', 'product_cat' ) ) {
        woocommerce_get_template_part( 'single-product-shop' );
    } else {
        woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );
    }
```

Comment: I understand this - Its what I've overwritten. I was looking for a way to use this and a conditional to load another template that I've created for the shop category?

Comment: I just proposed this, because it's probably best to use function available for this purpose. Besides that, are you sure you have the file in right place, because your error message suggest otherwise. @user2478101

Comment: Thanks Ialocin - this makes sense to me now. I've got the file in themes/choosentheme/woocommerce/single-product-shop.php, guessing I need to move it to the theme root.

Comment: I'll try this and then tick your awnser.