# How to have a custom display for both woocommerce archive and product-category pages?

Tags: php, templates, woocommerce-offtopic

## So far

Hi there, I understand my question is very closely related to a common question about 'woocommerce'.

I have been using a variety of woo hooks, filters and creating copies of original woo template files in my child theme in a folder called woocommerce/.

This is working and I'm able to make the edits that integrate woocommerce into my theme.

## What I'm trying to do

*Woocommerce uses archive-product.php to display product categories. It also uses this template to display the products of the category.*

**I'd like to style the products page very differently to the category page and create another archive template that displays the products of a category**

I'm thinking that using a new products-product.php template page or would be my best option. I'm very interested in learning more and more about the plug-in, therefore I'm trying to stay away from quick CSS fixes and learn to use the template files and hooks.

**Advice or points in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.**

Comment: Have you try a page builder plugin? You can create a custom archive-products page, and display the products as you like. There are some free page builders wich are very good (like: [http://siteorigin.com/page-builder/](http://siteorigin.com/page-builder/))

Comment: This question has been put on hold due to being off topic. Could someone explain to me briefly how it is? I've discovered a very simple answer that is very specific to the plug-in and not general coding. I see a lot of questions very similar to this the site. Thanks

Comment: You are right there are many questions similar to this one not deemed to be off-topic, but generally the rules is »we **do not handle** (..) **questions concerning third party plugins and themes**« as stated on the [on-topic help page](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Which would be, because woocommerce is clearly a third party plugin, the reason for putting this on hold. Btw please do not push your question by making irrelevant/minor edits, just to keep it up in the queue.

Comment: I do apologise, the way it was implied I thought that it was more about how I worded the question. Could you tell me if this question is going to be taken down? I think it should considering it goes no where and the answers are miss leading to the actual solution. Thanks for explaining to me about the question. I know now.

Comment: You always can take down your questions yourself by deleting them. I'm not 100% sure how this is handled if the questions stays, but is on hold, I think if there are answers it will remain, at least a while. But, although I didn't test it, I'm fairly certain that my first answer is a sufficient solution for this problem. Btw I updated my answer with information for you on how to do it more woocommerce specific.

Comment: Btw sorry, if I've been wrongly accusing you there.

Comment: Great @ialocin, thanks for taking the time to do that. I found that the product category page was being handled in taxonomy-product_cat.php. It basically calls the archive-product.php template. So, I just changed that to load my own template. It was one of the only files I didn't open. I agree the solution you offered is a perfect method for doing what I wanted to and will help me in the future I'm sure. As well as being an introduction to template_include. No bad feelings at all. I'm only learning how to use the forum correctly and be a part of the wordpress community. Cheers

Comment: This is a wordpress question that also applies to WP plugins. The answer is wordpress code.  There are better wordpress answers out there but because it was closed the community cannot add to it.  What was gained by closing it?

Comment: This off-topic policy is really annoying and frankly stupid. Wordpress is an open-source platform - there are many people out there working with woocommerce. When we want to bend it, break it, alter it, stackexchange should be there to help us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, you can tell WordPress to load a different template. The mostly seen approaches make either use of the [`template_redirect`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) or the [`template_include`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include) hook. It is preferable to use `template_include` as described in this [article](http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2014/02/19/template_redirect-is-not-for-loading-templates/). Following an example on how to approach this:

**Code:**

```
// load the woocommerce category archive template
add_filter( 'template_include', 'wpse138858_woocommerce_category_archive_template' );
function wpse138858_woocommerce_category_archive_template( $original_template ) {
    // we're loading the template conditionally, 
    // but only if we're actually on a woocommerce category archive
    if ( is_product_category() ) {
        // you've to create the template you want to use here first
        return get_template_directory().'/woocommerce-category-archive.php';
    } else {
        return $original_template;
    }
}
```

*Additional information:*

- [Woocommerce Conditional Tags](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/conditional-tags/)

*Notes:*

- untested
- There might be a more specific way to do this for/with woocommerce, depending on how they handle there template loading. For that you have to extend your research and/or dive into the woocommerce code.

---

*Edit:*

What you are looking for - if you want to do it the woocommerce way - is the function [`wc_get_template_part()`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/v2.1.5/includes/wc-core-functions.php#L55) - formerly, pre WC 2.1, [`woocommerce_get_template_part()`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/v2.1.5/includes/wc-deprecated-functions.php#L122), now deprecated. I've given an [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/125154/22534) on how to use the latter some time ago, you can do it for the newly named - the functionality is the same - function accordingly. The answer of course regards the direct use of the function, in your case you probably want and should make use of the correspondent hook [`wc_get_template_part`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/v2.1.5/includes/wc-core-functions.php#L74). With this information on hand you should be able to do this the woocommerce way.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I'm still on the mission to find a solution that is more specific to woo commerce, but this would work. Thanks again @ialocin

Comment: As @RobertWilkins says: »This code worked perfectly for me and has ended a few hours of head scratching... Thanks so much!!!«

Comment: @RobertWilkins Thanks for that, but this isn't something viable for an edit, so I added it for you as a comment.