# Different custom templates for product category

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I want to have multiple different templates depending on product category. Looking at [Template for different category on woocommerce product](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/125153/template-for-different-category-on-woocommerce-product) I sort of got it working

I've copied `single-product.php` into `theme-folder/woocommerce/` and have updated the code to be

```
            <?php the_post(); ?>

            <?php
                //wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );
            if( has_term( 'course', 'product_cat' ) ) {
                wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product-course' );
            } else {
                wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );
            }

            ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

Then I've created two files in `theme-folder/woocommerce/` - `content-single-product.php` and `content-single-product-course.php`

Both seem to display fine when viewing the individual products, however, viewing the product with the `course` the template displays an error, (although it does still render the HTML)

`Warning: include(/site/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-bookings/templates/booking-form/.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /site/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php on line 345`

```
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0009  413744  {main}( )   .../index.php:0
2   0.0010  415328  require( '/site/wp-blog-header.php' )   .../index.php:17
3   1.8879  63328264    require_once( '/site/wp-includes/template-loader.php' ) .../wp-blog-header.php:19
4   1.9015  63307352    include( '/site/wp-content/themes/dyfi-storefront-child/woocommerce/single-product.php' )   .../template-loader.php:106
5   1.9950  64097248    wc_get_template_part( ) .../single-product.php:44
6   1.9952  64098072    load_template( )    .../wc-core-functions.php:284
7   1.9954  64101152    require( '/site/wp-content/themes/dyfi-storefront-child/woocommerce/content-single-product-course.php' )    .../template.php:772
8   1.9970  64113712    do_action( )    .../content-single-product-course.php:62
9   1.9970  64114088    WP_Hook->do_action( )   .../plugin.php:470
10  1.9970  64114088    WP_Hook->apply_filters( )   .../class-wp-hook.php:327
11  2.0539  64450192    woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart( )  .../class-wp-hook.php:303
12  2.0539  64450248    do_action( )    .../wc-template-functions.php:1667
13  2.0540  64450624    WP_Hook->do_action( )   .../plugin.php:470
14  2.0540  64450624    WP_Hook->apply_filters( )   .../class-wp-hook.php:327
15  2.0540  64451752    WC_Booking_Cart_Manager->add_to_cart( ) .../class-wp-hook.php:303
16  2.0554  64565880    wc_get_template( )  .../class-wc-booking-cart-manager.php:63
17  2.0558  64573392    include( '/site/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-bookings/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/booking.php' ) .../wc-core-functions.php:345
18  2.0559  64573432    WC_Booking_Form->output( )  .../booking.php:41
19  2.0993  64632408    wc_get_template( )  .../class-wc-booking-form.php:400
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use get_template_part('yourfile') instead.

the get_template_part() goes from theme root path.

so if you have your template in woocommerce folder use:

```php
if( has_term( 'course', 'product_cat' ) ) {
   get_template_part('woocommerce/single-product-course' );
} else {
   wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );
}
```

however probably should be better to make a folder that its not woocommerce, once woocoomerce folder will searched for woocommerce files, and if there is somewhere a file with that name with make conflict.

also, are you calling the single-product template from the same file, probably would be better to make a second file and paste the code there.